# Why the passwords don't match in symfony after migration?

Tags: symfony, passwords

Currently we are migrating our website to another server, but we are still using the same database.

So we have 2 exact websites connected to 1 database.

On the first one we can log in with the defaul credentials, and on the other the passwords do not match.

This is how we check if the password matches:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

public function checkCredentials($password, UserInterface $user ){
   return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $password );
}
```

This is my security config:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
# ...
```

is there some hash that I have to use in order to obtain the same password?

Comment: If you are using ['auto' hasher](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html#the-auto-hasher), you might have different "best" hashers on each server. you may need to specify the hasher you are using on both to ensure they are the same

Comment: @craigh , where is this hash stored? I should be able to copy it and use it on the other server no ...?

Comment: It sounds like you need to familiarize yourself with Symfony security. That topic is far too broad to cover here. The hash is stored in your DB. When logging in, the string that is entered as a password is hashed by the security component and compared with the value in the DB. The hasher that is being used sounds like it possibly isn't the correct one, which is why your strings don't match.